# How should I set a path name in C# using a mac

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm learning C# and need to set path name. All the examples I see are using windows, and I can't seem to do this on a mac.

I just get a blank terminal using the below

```
var files = Directory.GetDirectories(@"Users/andre/documents", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var file in files){
                Console.WriteLine(file);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Programming for mac propably means .NET Core. Not my area of expertise, but I can give you some hint.

It looks like what you want is the Special Folder of the user. The proper way to go about that in Windows is the [SpecialFolders Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.7.2). While I am not sure, this should map to something comparable on a Mac. And according to Documentation they are support as of .NET Core 2.0.

Also if you want to build paths, use the Path class. It can deal with the specifics of how each OS views paths.